# jQuery filter to select first two and then next two

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list:

```
<li class="list one" data-number="2"></li>
<li class="list one" data-number="2"></li>
<li class="list two" data-number="3"></li>
<li class="list two" data-number="7"></li>
```

And I need to pass each value from `data-number` attribute to a variable based on the list class.

I have these functions for that:

```
var list_one = 0;
var list_two = 0;

$(".one").each(function (i, val) {
  var number = $(this).data('number')
  list_one = list_one + parseInt(number); // Gives 4
});

$(".two").each(function (i, val) {
  var number = $(this).data('number')
  list_two = list_two + parseInt(number); // Gives 10
});
```

But as the list grows, this becomes a long and messy code. What's the best way to get the values from the first two `li`, and then the two next, etc and pass the sum to the variable?

The list will always have this structure, so I don't need to concider that the number of `li`s with each class will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain an object of summed values:

```js
var result = {};

$('.list').each(function(idx, ele) {
    var key = ele.classList.toString().replace(/ /g,  '_');
    result[key] = (+result[key] || 0) +  +ele.dataset["number"];
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
    <li class="list one" data-number="2">one</li>
    <li class="list one" data-number="2">one</li>
    <li class="list two" data-number="3">two</li>
    <li class="list two" data-number="7">tow</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work, it saves a sum of every two numbers. So if you have 20 elements, listValues will have a length of 10

```
var listValues = [];
$('li.list').each(function(i, val){
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
       listValues[] = parseInt($(this).data('number'));
   } else {
       listValues[listValues.length - 1] += parseInt($(this).data('number'));
   }
});
```